# is there any Mysql backup and restore java api

Tags: java, mysql

.NET uses references to make a mysql backup and restore. But i cannot find any .jar libraries in java for mysql backup and restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backup and restore MySQL using the mysqldump utility provided by MySQL.

accessing this utility from java using Proces will do the job neatly.

```
Process backup = null;
            try {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                backup = runtime.exec("mysqldump -uroot -pdbpass --add-drop-database -B dbname -r " + "filepath" + "Filename" + ".sql");//change the dbpass and dbname with your dbpass and dbname

                int dumpCompleted = backup.waitFor();

                if (dumpCompleted == 0) {

                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");("Could not create the backup");
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

To restore the databases,

```
Process restoreProcess=null;
        try {
        String restoreCommand= "mysql ", "--user=" + dbUserName, "--password=" + dbPassword, "-e", "source " + source"
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            restoreProcess = runtime.exec(restoreCommand);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Restored successfully!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not restore the backup!");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```